# How can I get two UL's in table-cell-formatted DIV's to be flush against the top?

Tags: jquery, html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".collection").sortable({});

  jQuery('li', jQuery('.collection')).draggable({
    'connectToSortable': '.collection',
    'cancel': 'a.ui-icon',
    'revert': 'invalid',
    'containment': 'document',
    'cursor': 'move'
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: silver;
  font-family: Verdana, Georgia;
}

div.main {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 740px;
}

div.table {
  display: table;
  width: 740px;
}

div.td {
  display: table-cell;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

div.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

ul.collection {
  background-color: white;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

ul.collection>li {}

ul#selection {
  right: 0;
}

ul#source {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/page.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
          <ul id="source" class="collection">
            <li class="draggable">Everything</li>
            <li class="draggable">Nonfiction</li>
            <li class="draggable">Fiction</li>
            <li class="draggable">Poetry</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="td">
          <ul id="selection" class="collection">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(function() {
        jQuery(".collection").sortable({});

        jQuery('li', jQuery('.collection')).draggable({
          'connectToSortable': '.collection',
          'cancel': 'a.ui-icon',
          'revert': 'invalid',
          'containment': 'document',
          'cursor': 'move'
        });
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This script is intended to make LI's draggable between two UL's. When this runs, the populated UL in the left table-cell-styled DIV is not flush up against the top of the table-styled DIV; it appears that its top is loosely (or exactly) aligned with the bottom of the empty table-cell to the right. The initial image, with a different background, is as follows:

[image: A staggered view of parts of the table]

If both UL's have at least one LI, then they are aligned flush towards the top as desired. If the last LI is dragged over, there can be a flicker effect. The desired flush appearance is:

[image: The desired effect, which appears when both lists have at least one item.]

I'd like to set things so that both UL's are at the top of what should be their simulated table-cell's whether they are populated or empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertically *align* the `table-cell`s by using `vertical-align: top` on the `div.td` element. This will tell the `table-cell` to *stick* to the top.

See demo below:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".collection").sortable({});

  jQuery('li', jQuery('.collection')).draggable({
    'connectToSortable': '.collection',
    'cancel': 'a.ui-icon',
    'revert': 'invalid',
    'containment': 'document',
    'cursor': 'move'
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: silver;
  font-family: Verdana, Georgia;
}

div.main {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 740px;
}

div.table {
  display: table;
  width: 740px;
}

div.td {
  display: table-cell;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

div.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

ul.collection {
  background-color: white;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

ul.collection>li {}

ul#selection {
  right: 0;
}

ul#source {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/page.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
          <ul id="source" class="collection">
            <li class="draggable">Everything</li>
            <li class="draggable">Nonfiction</li>
            <li class="draggable">Fiction</li>
            <li class="draggable">Poetry</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="td">
          <ul id="selection" class="collection">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(function() {
        jQuery(".collection").sortable({});

        jQuery('li', jQuery('.collection')).draggable({
          'connectToSortable': '.collection',
          'cancel': 'a.ui-icon',
          'revert': 'invalid',
          'containment': 'document',
          'cursor': 'move'
        });
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've thought further and would like LI's to switch to the other UL if clicked. Is that best done with a jQuery.click() that removes the LI from its present UL and appends it to the other, or is there a better way with the gadgetry in place? TIA,